# Filter e-mail links to deleted question

Tags: support, tags, deleted-questions, email

I am subscribed to new questions in the "model-theory" tag on Maths.SE. So today, I got an e-mail with a single new question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502074/is-acla-of-model-theory-definable

The problem is relatively simple: This question has been removed by its author. As such, I contend it is not relevant any more (since I don't have over 10k rep). So, this question ought not to show up in the e-mail; consequently, the entire e-mail is superfluous.

So, two questions:

> 1. Are these deleted questions being sent in the e-mail intentionally, or is this a bug? (Please delete one of [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) accordingly.)
> 2. If the former, can <10k users be exempted from getting them, as they're useless for them anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these deleted questions being sent in the e-mail intentionally, or is this a bug?

No, deleted questions shouldn't be emailed out. However, calling this a bug is most likely also incorrect.

I don't have the timestamp of when the email was sent to you, but the question was probably emailed sometime between being asked and deleted (4.5 hour window there):

> asked 5 hours ago
>
> deleted by user48900 29 mins ago

Comment: I thought of that possibility, but it seemed unlikely that the deletion occurred in the ~10-15 minutes between receiving the e-mail and my viewing (turns out it was deleted about 5 minutes after the e-mail). Thanks for your time.